# Use a Dropdown Value to Select a Table's Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a drop down with my table column headers. Now I would like to use the drop down values in table formulas. The function normally is `=SUM(Table2[Header1])`, but I would like to do something like `=SUM(Table2[ & E1 & ])`. `E1` being my headers in my drop down list. I keep getting an error. Is there a way around this or a different approach?

[image]

Comment: You might be able to use a formula called `INDIRECT` http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html which lets you create a range using a `CONCATENATE`. I've used it to reference a range, but not a column in a table

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out and let you know.

Comment: Your awesome. `INDIRECT` worked perfectly.Thanks. I used the formula `=SUM(INDIRECT("Table2[" & E1 & "]"))` and got the result I wanted. Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: Be aware that INDIRECT() is volatile and may cause slowness in files with many formulas.